# Getting a pointer to image memory / framebuffer in OpenGL ES2

Tags: c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am an OpenGL newbie and I am looking for a way to get a pointer to the memory that contains the pixel data of my rendered output. I am using OpenGL ES2 and I am on an embedded system where the graphics card shares memory with the other processing units, if that is of any help.

I am aware of [this very old discussion](https://community.khronos.org/t/pointer-to-framebuffer/49936/51) on the Khronos forums, which delves into why it would be a great or terrible idea, but does not help me.

Is there any way to achieve something like this?

**EDIT** The reason why I don't see how I can use `glReadPixels` (without copying the data) is that I need to feed the memory region containing the pixel data to a driver. I'd rather avoid copying the data on every frame.

Comment: The standard approach is calling `glReadPixels`, so can you explain why that is not sufficient?

Comment: @Botje I'll make an edit to the question because I assume other people will have that question, too.

Comment: Assuming you have tried glReadPixels and found it insufficient, you will need to give us more details about your OpenGL driver and available extensions.

Comment: @Botje thanks, please bear with me because I am probably thinking about this all wrong due to lack of OpenGL experience. I am on a Xilinx UltraScale+ MPSoC, which sports an ARM Mali 400 MP-2 graphics card. The driver is provided by Xilinx (https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/18841928/Xilinx+Arm+Mali-400+Driver), but there's no information about extensions and neither is there in the user manual. Which (if any) of the extensions listed here (https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Extension#Common_extensions) would help me? Maybe then I can just see if I can use it.

Comment: It's probably easier to hook the buffer in the kernel  - e.g. pick up the Linux DRM handle, and import the memory through the low level DRM memory management and sync routines rather than OpenGL ES.

Comment: The only somewhat standard extension for this is AMD_pinned_memory, which is AMD-only.

Comment: @Botje oh heck, pity this is not available on my ARM Mali... :(

Comment: If the objective is to capture an image snapshot from the color buffer (source) after rendering, it's important to recognize that the source image may not be stored as a contiguous block of memory due to considerations like memory packing, alignment, or differences in data format (e.g., BGR to RGB). The use of glReadPixels may introduce performance overhead because it handles these necessary conversions, ensuring data accuracy at the expense of speed.